# Max CDN purge through API

Tags: php, api

I am trying to purge a file through the MaxCDN API but it's not working. Here's the code I'm using. The `print_r` doesn't return any result.

```
function purge() {
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
    $date = date('c');
    $apiid = 'myapiid';
    $apikey = 'myapi';
    $auth_key = hash('sha256', $date.':'.$apikey.':purge');
    $url = 'http://softsailor.alexdumitru.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/themes/ss3/includes/sprite.jpg';
    if (!class_exists('IXR_Client')) {
        require_once (ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-IXR.php');
    }
    $client = new IXR_Client('api.netdna.com','/xmlrpc/cache',80);
    $client->timeout = 30;
    $client->query('cache.purge', $apiid, $auth_string, $date, $url);
    print_r($client->getResponse());
}
```

I turned debug on and I'm getting the following error
    Something went wrong - -32300 : transport error - HTTP status code was not 200

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey Alex. I work at MaxCDN and here is a code example that I took from our Wiki:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
include("lib/xmlrpc.inc");
$cur = date('c');
$apiKey = 'api-key';
$apiUserId = 'api-user-id';
$namespace = 'cache';
$method = 'purge';
$authString = hash('sha256', $cur . ':' . $apiKey . ':' . $method);

// this is the url to purge
$url= 'http://static.jdorfman.netdna-cdn.com/static/images/frugal-it-logo.png';
$f=new xmlrpcmsg("$namespace.$method", array(php_xmlrpc_encode($apiUserId),
php_xmlrpc_encode($authString), php_xmlrpc_encode($cur),
php_xmlrpc_encode($url)));
$c=new xmlrpc_client("/xmlrpc/cache", "api.netdna.com", 80,'http11');
$r=&$c->send($f);
print_r($r);
?>
```

If you have any other questions or concerns feel free to get in contact with me: jdorfman at maxcdn dot com

Comment: Do you have a working example for .Net?  I'm working with the example from the NetDNA API page and neither of the purge operations is working.  Calling "purgeAllCache" returns "Invalid Auth String" (which I'm pretty sure it isn't) and "purge" returns "Failed to parse request".

Answer (score 1):

jdorfman's example dumps the entire raw response but if you are like me you want to get it into data objects using php

Here are some helpful tips:

$r->serialize()  to access just the raw XML response

to convert to JSON use this:

$xml =  simplexml_load_string($r->serialize());
   echo json_encode($xml);